# Stream stdout from subprocess to python function, and back to subprocess

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

I am trying to use python in a unix style pipe. 
For example, in unix I can use a pipe such as:

```
$ samtools view -h somefile.bam | python modifyStdout.py | samtools view -bh - > processed.bam
```

I can do this by using a `for line in sys.stdin:` loop in the python script and that appears to work without problems.

However I would like to internalise this unix command into a python script. The files involved will be large so I would like to avoid blocking behaviour, and basically stream between processes.

At the moment I am trying to use `Popen` to manage each command, and pass the stdout of the first process to the stdin of the next process, and so on.

In a seperate python script I have (sep_process.py):

```python
import sys

f = open("sentlines.txt", 'wr')
f.write("hi")
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
    f.write(line)
f.close()
```

And in my main python script I have this:

```python
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# Generate an example file to use
f = open('sees.txt', 'w')
f.write('somewhere over the\nrainbow')
f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Use grep as an example command
    p1 = Popen("grep over sees.txt".split(), stdout=PIPE)

    # Send to sep_process.py 
    p2 = Popen("python ~/Documents/Pythonstuff/Bam_count_tags/sep_process.py".split(), stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)   

    # Send to final command
    p3 = Popen("wc", stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=PIPE)

    # Read output from wc
    result = p3.stdout.read()
    print result
```

The p2 process however fails `[Errno 2] No such file or directory` even though the file exists.

Do I need to implement a `Queue` of some kind and/or open the python function using the multiprocessing module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @cdarke, that solved the problem for using simple commands like grep, wc etc. However I was too stupid to get subprocess.Popen to work when using an executable such as samtools to provide the data stream.

To fix the issue, I created a string containing the pipe exactly as I would write it in the command line, for example:

```python
sam = '/Users/me/Documents/Tools/samtools-1.2/samtools'
home = os.environ['HOME']    
inpath = "{}/Documents/Pythonstuff/Bam_count_tags".format(home)

stream_in = "{s} view -h {ip}/test.bam".format(s=sam, ip=inpath)
pyscript = "python {ip}/bam_tags.py".format(ip=inpath)
stream_out = "{s} view -bh - > {ip}/small.bam".format(s=sam, ip=inpath)

# Absolute paths, witten as a pipe
fullPipe = "{inS} | {py} | {outS}".format(inS=stream_in, 
                                              py=pyscript,
                                              outS=stream_out)

print fullPipe
# Translates to >>>
# samtools view -h test.bam | python ./bam_tags.py | samtools view -bh - > small.bam
```

I then used `popen` from the `os` module instead and this worked as expected:

```
os.popen(fullPipe)
```

Answer (score 1):

The tilde `~` is a shell expansion.  You are not using a shell, so it is looking for a directory called `~`.

You could read the environment variable `HOME` and insert that.  Use

```
os.environ['HOME']
```

Alternatively you could use `shell=True` if you can't be bothered to do your own expansion.